# Issues in launching Pentaho Kettle spoon on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: x11, ubuntu-12.04, kettle

I have untared the latest kettle stable version pdi-ce-4.3.0-stable.tar.gz and then tried to start spoon by typing spoon.sh from the command prompt. But it fails with the following exception

```
**org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]**
    **at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)**
```

I have spent quite a lot of time searching for the solution and all those pointers in vain till now.

I installed the following based on the instructions on several forums:

- Xorg, X11
- Gtk
- Xinit
- Xulrunner
- Firefox
- gnome
- ubuntu-desktop

But none of these helped. Thinking that spoon may depend on the X-Windows server, i tried to check if its running and used the command startx on Xinit to start the X server. But unfortunately, it failed with the error as follows

```
Fatal server error:
no screens found

xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
xinit: server error
```

I am clueless now. Can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to start kettle spoon from a real console. this is not going to work. you need a real X session. **Spoon is a GUI**, so login under your X environment (usually GDM).

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

After that, open a gnome console and execute ./spoon.sh . Maybe you are trying to exetute pan.sh or kitchen.sh? those will run fine under console without graphic envionment.

Comment: After gdm installation, i tried to run gdm by typing gdm in the shell but i get the following message and i do not see any console. Am i opening gnome the wrong way?

**gdm-binary[13409]: WARNING: Unable to load file '/etc/gdm/custom.conf': No such file or directory
gdm-binary[13409]: WARNING: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.088257 seconds
gdm-binary[13409]: WARNING: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log for errors**

Comment: I have noticed the following error under /var/log/Xorg.0.log when gdm is run

'Fatal server error:
no screens found'

Does it suggest anything?

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

Comment: Tried these and it did not help. I still get the same issue. Would this have anything to do with the driver? 
Another input is that i use this ubuntu instance on AWS EC2. I login from my windows machine using SSH with Putty.

Comment: you can not use pentaho spoon without graphic environment

Comment: I suspect that there is something wrong with the graphics driver.  

For now, going with the workaround to use spoon from windows and then run the created kettle jobs using kitchen in ubuntu. This way i dont need graphic environment on ubuntu.

Comment: Perhaps, opening spoon GUI from Ubuntu box itself is critical as it tries to connect to the running hadoop, hbase etc during job design itself. Connectivity from windows to ubuntu may not work always due to firewall restrictions etc.

Comment: FWIW, at home I run Spoon on my Ubuntu server from my Mac with SSH and X forwarding.